# AWS Lambda does not seem to get an private IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am testing the [Vault Lambda Extension](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/aws/lambda-extension) which allows to reads secrets from Hashicorp Vault without using tokens.

I therefore created a demo lambda function which use the layer "Vault Lambda Extension".
The lambda crashes before the python code is run.

Example of the execution result:

```
foo

Response
{
  "errorType": "Extension.Crash",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: b16468f9-009c-4b1a-91ca-8b0899e01b7c Error: exit status 1"
}

Function Logs
2023-02-15T18:15:10.999Z [INFO]  vault-lambda-extension: Initialising
2023-02-15T18:15:11.006Z [ERROR] Fatal error, exiting: error="error logging in to Vault: read tcp 169.254.76.1:39510->10.73.1.100:8200: read: connection reset by peer"
EXTENSION   Name: vault-lambda-extension    State: Started  Events: []
2023-02-15T18:15:12.712Z [INFO]  vault-lambda-extension: Initialising
2023-02-15T18:15:12.773Z [ERROR] Fatal error, exiting: error="error logging in to Vault: read tcp 169.254.76.1:39514->10.73.1.100:8200: read: connection reset by peer"
EXTENSION   Name: vault-lambda-extension    State: Started  Events: []
START RequestId: b16468f9-009c-4b1a-91ca-8b0899e01b7c Version: $LATEST
RequestId: b16468f9-009c-4b1a-91ca-8b0899e01b7c Error: exit status 1
Extension.Crash
END RequestId: b16468f9-009c-4b1a-91ca-8b0899e01b7c
REPORT RequestId: b16468f9-009c-4b1a-91ca-8b0899e01b7c  Duration: 1694.95 ms    Billed Duration: 1695 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 24 MB
```

This lambda is our Dev VPC private subnet.
We are therefore expecting it would receive a private IP address of this subnet CIDR.
But as you can see the address IP of the lambda is 169.254.76.1 (which is a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv4), an address used by Linux when it is not able to set an private IP address ).

The role (modified) set for this lambda is

```
{
  "partial": false,
  "policies": [
    {
      "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
      "document": {
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": [
              "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
              "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
              "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
              "ec2:DescribeInstances",
              "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
              "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
              "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
              "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
              "logs:CreateLogGroup",
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
              "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
              "logs:PutLogEvents",
              "logs:GetLogEvents",
              "logs:FilterLogEvents"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        ],
        "Version": "2012-10-17"
      },
      "id": "ANPATRANPATRANPATRANPAT",
      "name": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
      "type": "managed"
    }
  ],
  "resources": {
    "ec2": {
      "service": {
        "icon": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2a...CAgPC9nPgogIDwvZz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==",
        "name": "Amazon EC2"
      },
      "statements": [
        {
          "action": "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "ec2",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "ec2",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "ec2",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "ec2",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "ec2",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "ec2",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "ec2",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "ec2",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "logs": {
      "service": {
        "icon": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAg...z4KICA8L2c+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=",
        "name": "Amazon CloudWatch Logs"
      },
      "statements": [
        {
          "action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "logs",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "logs",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "logs",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "logs",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "logs:PutLogEvents",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "logs",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "logs:GetLogEvents",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "logs",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "logs:FilterLogEvents",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "logs",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "aws_iam_policy_lambda_vault_lab",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "roleName": "lambda_role_vault_lab",
  "trustedEntities": [
    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  ]
}
```

I don't include the python code has the lambda crashs before starting executing it.
For info, I tried a few changes in the policy without any effects.
Has someone an idea where I did go wrong?

Thanks, :)

David

Comment: Why do you say that the Lambda function doesn't get a private IP? How does that relate to the apparent layer failure of "error logging in to Vault"?

Comment: All IP's you show are private, either link-local (the 169.254 address) or the 10.x (class A non-routable).  It's unclear what external routing you have setup.

Comment: I modified the question to reflect slightly your similar questions about the IP address.
As I mentionned, the lambda is in one of our VPC, therefore it should get an address of the VPC CIDR and not a link-local address.
@jarmod I mentionned the layer because it is the part which crashes. It crashes because it can not connect to the vault because of the wrong IP address of the lambda.

Comment: @stdunbar I am trying accessing to a vault server in the VPC where the Lambda is supposed to be therefore I believe I should not care about the routing part, no?

Comment: If you configure the Lambda function to attach to a private subnet in your VPC then the Lambda function is assigned to a Hyperplane ENI whose IP address comes from the subnet's IP range afaik. Each ENI is dedicated to a subnet/security group pair. Your vault server should allow inbound traffic on the appropriate port from the security group associated with the Lambda function.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod Yes, except that the Lambda does not seems to get an IP from the Hyperplane ENI because the address IP of the lambda is 169.254.76.1 and not 10.73.1.x)
I did not know about the hyperplane ENI, I shall have a look at its documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Could my issue being that the Networking is not resolved before the layer is applied? I mean, could the layer be executed before the networking has given an IP address to the lambda?

Comment: ENIs are created when the Lambda function is created or updated, not when the function is invoked. This video on [AWS Lambda networking best practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ax6cnBEDnsM) is a helpful deep dive.

Comment: thank you very much @jarmod. I shall read that straight away.